# How can i add an glass objet to an motion tracked scene with proper light coming through it?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, transparency, tracking, glass, compositing-nodes

i have a scene with a cg glass cup and there is no light coming through it, how can i fix that, i thought about HDRI but i dont know if that would help, im quite new to 3d modelling and everything in this area.

Answer (score 0):

You can either create an HDRI with a smartphone or a 3d camera for best results. That would give you a good base to work with when it comes to lighting.

[Tutorial on how to make an HDRI](https://youtu.be/etOkgjrTfa8)

Another option would be to have a look at the scene you are tracking (if it is a video you took) and try to replicate the lighting according to it. That could involve setting up a 'sun' light object, or multiple area lights.

[Tutorial that helps with recreating studio lighting for artistic renders, for example](https://youtu.be/RtTP5KlzUDo)

[Tutorial for helping you set up an HDRI if needed, starting from 14:29](https://youtu.be/hymtATx1QXw?t=869)